# String contém certa palavra

Tags: string, lua

Gostaria de checar se uma *string* contém certa palavra.

```
String = "oi\ntchau\nhi\nbye"
```

A *string* é dividida por `\n` (pula linha), gostaria que checasse entre cada linha, se contem a palavra inteira, já tentei e ainda não consegui.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Você pode usar as funções `match` ou `find` para achar a *string* que deseja. Ambas retornam um valor booleano indicado a presença da *string*

```
string.match("oi\ntchau\nhi\nbye", "hi")
```

[Documentação `match()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.match)

```
string.find("oi\ntchau\nhi\nbye", "hi")
```

[Documentação `find()`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.find)

Ambos resolvem seu problema se você quer apenas saber se contém ou não a *string* procurada. O resultado pode ser usado em um `if` sem problemas.

Caso não seja isto, você precisa ser mais específico na pergunta e mostre o que já fez, e aponte qual o problema.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7F1tu8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mtifgfbi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/StringMatch.lua).

Answer (score 7):

Para saber se a **palavra inteira** está na *string*, pode usar assim:

```
procuro = "tchau"
dentrode = "oi\ntchau\nhi\bye"

string.match( "\n" .. dentrode .. "\n", "\n" .. procuro .. "\n" )
```

Explicação:

- Usamos `"\n"` adicionais em `procuro` para pesquisar apenas palavras inteiras;
- Da mesma forma, adicionamos os `"\n"` em `dentrode`, pois se você procura a palavra inteira e ela estiver no começo ou no fim da string, vai ser encontrada da mesma forma.

Answer (score 3):

Possivelmente assim:

```
--remover todos os /n
local result = string.gsub(s, "n", " ") -- remove line breaks

--Depois procurar as palavras
str = "This is some text containing the word tiger."
if string.match(str, "tiger") then
  print ("The word tiger was found.")
else
  print ("The word tiger was not found.")
end
```